# Realize a multiseat system with a polarized 3D-monitor

Tags: debian, gnome3, gui, multi-monitor, multiseat

Besides playing 3D-material, modern 3D-TV-sets (using polarization technology) offer the possibility of [dual-play](http://www.theverge.com/2011/09/03/lg-dual-play-cinema-3d-tv-video-ifa-2011/).

While 3d-playback works with different polarization for the left and the right eye, with dual play 2 users can watch completely different 2d-material at the same time on the same screen. To make it work, each of the 2 users gets different glasses: one is horizontally polarized on both eyes, the other is only vertically polarized. By now, this technology is primarily used for 2 player games, to replace split screens.

My idea is to use this technology for a [multiseat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration) system (I would prefer using Debian).

For a multiseat-setup, one usually needs 2 keyboards, 2 mice, 2 video-cards and two screens, but when using a 3D-TV-set, one video card (and of course just one screen) should be sufficient.

Therefore, apart from the "normal" setup of a multiseat system, the major difficulty would be to get the two different video-signals to the TV-set like if they were just one stereoscopic signal. One possibility would be to send the two signals side-by-side or over-under.

So basically, the goal could be achieved with a setup like in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6o92RoCV8RU) but with display settings for a 3D-TV (and with a modern operating system, best would be debian with gnome 3).

Finally, I want to add that I don't own a 3D-TV yet, therefore I cannot verify your answer. Still I would be glad if somebody could discuss the feasibility of such a system.